# Modify params in r notebooks

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am writing a rnotebook.
In the `yaml` I have

````
---                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
title: "title"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
author: Me                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
output: html_notebook                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
inputs:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  runDate: !r Sys.Date()-1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
---                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

```{r, eval=FALSE}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    params$stuff <- 'toto'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
```
````

But when I do `rmarkdown::render('file.Rmd')` I am getting `Error in params$stuff = "toto" :cannot change value of locked binding for 'params'`

Why is that and how can I fix it ?

Comment: I can't find documentation for the behavior, but I consider it a reasonable safeguard against inadvertent corruption of your parameters.  If you need the ability to change the `params` object, I'd recommend using a work around such as `local_params <- params; local_params$stuff <- 'toto'` and building the rest of your document using `local_params`.  If you find yourself needing to do this often, you may need to reconsider how you are deciding which parameters to give your RMD.

Comment: @Benjamin that's what I did but I see no reason to prevent the user from modifying params... ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Came across a fix to an [unrelated issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/commit/72bc5add8f219a103ae49a377cab22de919cfab3) that provided the solution and the hint I needed for further reading.

See `?bindingIsLocked`

You can unlock the `params` binding with

````
```{r}
bindingIsLocked("params", env = .GlobalEnv)
unlockBinding("params", env = .GlobalEnv)
params$stuff <- 'toto'
```
````

I will continue with my caution against altering the parameters of a parameterized report.

Comment: Well done thanks, not sure I get your oint about param alteration, there might be plenty of cases where you want it but anyway, good to see that they do not forbid the user to do it (this I cannot stand)

Comment: @statquant I come back to eat my words. I have a use case where I need to do precisely this.