# Rmarkdown child documents do not detect their `params`

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a master Rmarkdown document into which I am including my individual chapters using `knitr`'s `child` option. Each chapter makes use of [rmarkdown parameters in its own YAML](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html).
Each chapter compiles well individually, but when put in this master document, I get the error

```
object: 'params' not found
```

I believe it is because when the child is knitted, knitr does not read the parameters in the YAML (which is an rmarkdown feature, not a knitr feature).

Is there some way I can make these available to knitr? Is there an "rmarkdown"-way of putting in child documents?

````
---
title: My thesis
---

blah blah.

# Introduction

```{r child='01-introduction.rmd'}
```

# Mathematical background

```{r child='02-mathsy-maths.rmd'}
```
````

Example `01-introduction.rmd`

```
---
title: Introduction
params:
    dataset: ABC
---
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I understand `knitr`, when you knit a child document, this document is evaluated in the context (ie environment) of the parent document.

So, I see 4 solutions.

#### Set the params in the main document

With this solution, params are controlled inside the `YAML` front-matter of the main document. I think it is the natural solution.

````
---
title: My thesis
params:
  dataset: ABC
---

blah blah.

# Introduction

```{r child='01-introduction.rmd'}
```

# Mathematical background

```{r child='02-mathsy-maths.rmd'}
```
````

#### Assign the params in the global environment

With this solution, params are controlled with `R` code inside the main document.

````
---
title: My thesis
---

blah blah.

# Introduction
```{r set-params, include=FALSE}
params <- list(dataset = "ABC")
```

```{r child='01-introduction.rmd'}
```

# Mathematical background

```{r child='02-mathsy-maths.rmd'}
```
````

#### Retrieve params of the child document

With this solution, params are controlled inside each child document. It is a variant of the previous solution.
In the main document, child document's params are read using `knitr::knit_params()` and then assigned in the global environment.

````
---
title: My thesis
---

blah blah.

```{r def-assign-params, include=FALSE}
assign_params <- function(file) {
  text <- readLines(file)
  knit_params <- knitr::knit_params(text)
  params <<- purrr::map(knit_params, "value")
}
```

# Introduction

```{r, include=FALSE}
assign_params('01-introduction.rmd')
```

```{r child='01-introduction.rmd'}
```

# Mathematical background

```{r child='02-mathsy-maths.rmd'}
```
````

#### Use a (hacky) hook to assign params temporarily

Here, I define a hook for a new `use.params` chunk option: this solution extends the previous one. When `use.params=TRUE` is used, this hook is run for each chunk of the child document.
Note that with this solution, you cannot use `params` in inline code.

````
---
title: "Main document"
---

```{r hook-def, include=FALSE}
params_cache <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())

knitr::knit_hooks$set(use.params = function(before, options, envir) {
  if (before && options$use.params) {
    if (exists("params", envir = envir)) {
      params_cache$params <- envir$params
    }
    text <- readLines(knitr::current_input(dir = TRUE))
    knit_params <- knitr::knit_params(text)
    envir$params <- purrr::map(knit_params, "value")
  }
  if (!before && options$use.params) {
    if (exists("params", envir = params_cache)) {
      envir$params <- params_cache$params
      rm("params", envir = params_cache)
    } else {
      rm("params", envir = envir)
    }
  }
})
```

blah blah.

# Introduction

```{r child='01-introduction.rmd', use.params=TRUE}
```

# Mathematical background

```{r child='02-mathsy-maths.rmd', use.params=TRUE}
```
````

Comment: Thanks - I'll try options 2/3. I must retain individual parameters in each child document, or else they cannot be knitted standalone (and they are not the same for each child document). I thought there might be a way to do it without manually assigning params.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Due to [these lines](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/7386aa3960e8126f8accaa35341b578b7af44277/R/output.R#L238), I think params have to be assigned.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee I found a way to use a `knitr` hook. I updated my answer. I think this is closed to what you expected.

Comment: This seems not to work, at least when using the "knit" button in RStudio, as params is in a locked environment? `params <<- <something>` is thus an error.

Comment: @StuartR.Jefferys worked for me with `unlockBinding` https://stackoverflow.com/a/41979764/1454785